# How to change font size in iOS Picker Wheel

Tags: html, mobile, mobile-safari

I am writing a webpage and sometimes the "picker" wheel on select elements scales the font down so that it can all be read and sometimes it just puts the "..." in the text to shorten it but leaves the size of the font untouched.

Is there a way to specify which method is used? I would like the font size to be scaled appropriately.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You use the picker data source method that returns a view, not a string. In the view you put a label, and set the font options as you want there:

```
– pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView:
```

Comment: This looks to me like Objective-C. I need to be able to control this in HTML5 and JavaScript. Is this a feature I can set in my HTML page?

Comment: Ooops- well this is the problem with adding your post to "iOS".